# How can I insert text before and after a DOM Node in PHP?

Tags: php, class, dom, nodes, codeblocks

I am creating a twig file from a dom object and I want to add a code block around a particular div so that down the track I can use it in twig.

So the html code I have now is like:

```
<div>
  <div class="class1 class2">
    <div>
      Some content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to change it to (formatting is not important):

```
<div>
  {% block topBar %}
    <div class="class1 class2">
      <div>
        Some content here
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

So I have done something like:

```
$pullURL = "http://example.com";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTMLFile($pullURL);
$domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
$topBar = $domx->query("//*[contains(@class, 'class1 class2')]");
$startTopBlock = $dom->createTextNode("{% block topBar %}");
$topBar[0]->insertBefore($startTopBlock, $topBar[0]);
```

however, I keep getting the message

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not
>   Found Error' in /path/to/file.php:41

where line 41 is the insertBefore code.

What is going to be the best way to wrap a dom object in text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I needed to insert it into the parent, so the correct code should be:

```
$topBar[0]->parentNode->insertBefore($startTopBlock, $topBar[0]);
```

and not

```
$topBar[0]->insertBefore($startTopBlock, $topBar[0]);
```

as I want to insert this code in the parent before $topBar[0]. Everything else was correct.